# Measure Firebase bandwidth in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, bandwidth

My app is sending roughly 5mb a day, where as my calculations of what it should be were closer to less than 100kb.  So somewhere something is going very wrong or I am misunderstanding something.  Is there any way to log the size of the firebase data going in and out as it happens?  Otherwise, any other debugging ideas?

Every 2 mins this fires:

```
 long nowMili = now.getTimeInMillis();
 double lat = location.getLatitude();
 double lng = location.getLongitude();
 Map<String, String> locationRec = new HashMap<>();
 locationRec.put("time", String.valueOf(nowMili));
 locationRec.put("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
 locationRec.put("lng", String.valueOf(lng));
 Firebase locationRecRef = new Firebase(FB.FBRef + "/locator/" + User.currentGroup + "/"  + FB.uid);
 locationRecRef.setValue(locationRec);
```

What the data typically looks like:

```
"Locations":{
  [groupName]:{
    [user]:{
      lat: "175.48598907719583",
      lng: "-37.99470968516994",
      time: "1454707169089"
     },
  },
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what code would help but I'll post some anyway.

Comment: android studio has a built-in network monitor.

Comment: If you call `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)` at the start of you app, you can see what that client is sending to/receiving from Firebase.

Comment: You'll see that it sends paths in addition to the data, that there's keep-alive messages and more. With that information and http://bit.ly/firebase-bandwidth, you should be able to get a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that helps a lot.  Also, can you let me know roughly how big you would expect a key/value pair like this to be? `eb5b3405-631d-4d9f-b5f1-405590e9d739: 
"19:04"` My test results are showing it should be roughly 1.5kb, where as I thought it it was 1 byte per charcter.